# DOMPDF deprecated on Ubuntu server?

Tags: laravel, dompdf

I put my Laravel project on an Ubuntu server with PHP 7.3.1, Apache and MySQL. When I run "barryvdh / laravel-dompdf" I get the following error:

```
"Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError" class is deprecated since Symfony 4.4. 16384
```

My "composer.json" is as follows:

```
"require": {
         "php": "> = 7",
         "barryvdh / laravel-dompdf": "^ 0.8.5",
         "fideloper / proxy": "^ 4.0",
         "illuminate / support": "^ 5.5 | ^ 6",
         "kylekatarnls / laravel-carbon-2": "^ 1.0.0",
         "laravel-frontend-presets / argon": "^ 1.0",
         "laravel / framework": "5.8. *",
         "laravel / tinker": "^ 1.0",
         "laravelcollective / html": "^ 5.8",
         "nesbot / carbon": "^ 2.22",
         "spatie / laravel-backup": "^ 6.3"
     },
```

What could be the mistake? Thank you very much

Comment: How you "put" your project in the server? Did you clone it from a repo and run composer install?

Comment: Try to run composer update, it should auto handle depedencies.

Comment: To upload into the server, I copy the project directory, run "composer update". Everything was updated. The system works perfect, except for the PDF generation that throws that error. Thanks a lot

Comment: What I would do, is remove the vendor directory and the composer.lock file, then run `composer install` from the project root directory

Comment: I have the same error, I must have another problem, thanks porloscerros!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have different setting in you dev server php.ini eg (error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED). You can try putting `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED);` in the boot() method of AppServiceProvider (taken from [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-disable-e-deprecated)).